# string Comparison

Tags: c++, string-comparison, strcmp

I want to compare two user input strings, but not able to do so...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv0[])
{
    string my_string;
    string my_string2;
    cout<<"Enter string"<<endl;
    cin>>my_string;
    cout<<"Enter 2nd string"<<endl;
    cin>>my_string2;
    cout<<my_string<<"  "<<my_string2;
    strcmp(my_string,my_string2);
    int result;
    result= strcmp(my_string,my_string2);
    cout<<result<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

***This error is appearing.***
Error   1   error C2664: 'strcmp' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'const char *' c:\users\asad\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\string\string\string.cpp    23  String

Comment: Note that _tmain is not standard C++.

Comment: @Cristina: maybe he's an eagle and is typing with his talons. http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using `std::string`, `strcmp` is unnecessary -- you can just use `<`, `==`, `!=`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Your includes:

Since you are including standard headers, they should be in <>

`#include <string>`
`#include <iostream>`

#include with "" is generally used for your own header files, not standard header files.

You are using C++, and therefore need not use strcmp. In C++, you can simply use == & != to compare two strings.

`if (my_string == my_string2) result = 0;

else result = 1;`

Also, if you want to convert a string to a const char*, you can use `mystring.c_str()`

Comment: To be more pedantic, the `strcmp` function applies to an array of characters terminated by a null (a.k.a. char *).  If you really need to use `strcmp`, then use it with the `c_str()` method of `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use strcmp note that it takes different parameters than the ones you used.

http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/string/strcmp

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is also

```
result= strcmp(my_string.c_str(),my_string2.c_str());
```

Comment: `string` has methods for that: `result = my_string.compare(my_string2)`